# What's the equation for a line when x is an array of multiple items?

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions, python

(Pictured below) I've used Matplotlib in Python to plot a line from a*x+b when
a = -1.1374117136001587
x = array([0.0427 , 0.46546, 0.05329, 0.95268, 0.98098, 0.08189])
b = -0.4280948340892792

I can't figure out what was done with the values in x to draw the line the way it's drawn. I tried mean, mean squared, sum, product and tried plotting all on the Desmos graph.
By eye-balling a recreation of the line it seems it drew this, with something near...
y=-0.3x-0.4280948340892792

I also tried looking in the Matplotlib code to find the equation

[A screen shot of all values in Python and the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDB4o.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red line fits your $ax+b$ rather well.  It should extend from about $(0,-0.428)$ to $(1,-1.565)$ and it looks like it does.  The $x,y$ values of the blue points match your arrays as well.  I don't see anything indicating where the arrays $x$ and $y$ came from.

Comment: I see. So only the 'a' and 'b' values ARE used to position the line after all? I know what threw me off, Matplotlib drastically skews the aspect ratio of their graphs depending on height and width. Though I still don't quite understand why this matplotlib command takes 'x' in when telling it to plot. A question for Matplot. [The x, and y values were created randomly. It was part of the code where I ran into this question, I thought 'y' point positions not relevant to the question.]